# Two 'equal' javascript objects not equal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

In an Angular application I am comparing two objects (The original object to the current object after the user has made changes).  The problem is, the two objects are not equal - even before any changes are made.  When debugging in the browser the two objects look exactly the same.  Below I tried `angular.equals()` but `comparison` evaluates to false:

```
ChangeTracker.protype.hasChanged = function (current) { 
  var comparison = angular.equals(this.original, current);    
  return !comparison;  
};
```

I also have tried Underscore's `_.isEqual` as well as the regular (`==`) and strict (`===`) equality operators.

I thought I might be comparing by reference but even when I wrap the objects in `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` the comparison still returns false.

Why else would two seemingly equal objects not be equal?

Comment: Two different objects are never "equal" unless they are literally the same object. not equal properties, but the same object.

Comment: keep in mind, `console.log()` runs in an asynchronous manner, so if the reference point that a variable is assigned to changes before console.log finishes, it will output the most current version. at each of the places you did the console logging, can you make a hard clone and output the clone? here's an easy function for it: `var hard_clone = function(obj) {
    if (null === obj || "object" !== typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
};`

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to work for me, what version of Angular are you using?  You can play with this simple example, if you change a value in one of the objects, it switches from `Objects are equal` to `Objects are not equal`.  See: http://plnkr.co/edit/3ojL8T7d3JeBXVObXtrK?p=preview Sounds like one object is getting decorated with some extra attribute causing them not to be equal.

Comment: @NicholasSmith I'm using AngularJS 1.2.24 - I think you must be right.  The object must be getting decorated with an extra attribute.  Now I just need to figure out why/where...  Thanks

Comment: I wonder if reversing the order of parameters to angular.equals would make a difference?  Such as `angular.equals(current, this.original)`?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a typo in your code, did you mean to return the value of comparison?

```
ChangeTracker.protype.hasChanged = function (current) { 
  var comparison = angular.equals(this.original, current);    
  return !compare;  
};
```

Looks like it should have been:

`return !comparison`

Comment: I concur with your answer.

Comment: My mistake.  Unfortunately that isn't the issue though.  Just a mistake copying into the post.